# How to pass HTML from info to MySQL database using Python?

Tags: python, html, mysql, database, flask

I am using Pyhton and Flask and I am trying to pass the information from HTML form to MySQL db. I am connected to the database and I know that it works because I tried it via terminal but I am not sure how to pass information from the HTML form!?
Can someone advise on this.
Thanks in advance!
SuYan

```
@app.route("/sign-up", methods=["POST"])
def signup():
    title = "Sign-up"
    return render_template("signup.html", title=title)
    def signup(): 
        name = request.form['name'] 
        age = request.form['age'] 
        pas = request.form['signup-button']
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO person (name, age) VALUES (%s,%s)", (name, age))
db.commit()
```

Comment: Making the form POST, and then using the database package in python...

Comment: Right.  You have a `<form>` that includes `<input>` fields and a submit button (either `<input>` or `<button>`.  The browser will take all the form fields and pack it into the request.  Flask will hand you that in the `request` object.  Please go find a good flask example.

Comment: Yes thats I have as you described it but if you have a look at code above am I passing the information from Python to MySQL correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route("/sign-up", methods=["GET","POST"])
def signup():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form['name'] 
        age = request.form['age'] 
        pas = request.form['signup-button']
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO person (name, age) VALUES (%s,%s)", (name, age))
        db.commit()
    title = "Sign-up"
    return render_template("signup.html", title=title)
```

Hey Su Yan, Use this and let me know if this works or error persists.

Comment: Hey! Just tried it dosent give any errors except when I click submit it says 405 Method Not Allowed but when I check my database (MySQL) the info that I typed is not there so something is off not sure what considering the database connected properly I am sure of that! Thanks SuYan